# Duplicate certificates in DSS/VRI dictionary PDFBox (PAdES-LT/LTA)

Tags: pdfbox, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pades

I'm using PDFBox to sign (PAdES -LTA) PDF documents.I was able to get a PAdES-LT signature, but when I checked the signature using [ETSI Signatures Conformance Checker](https://signatures-conformance-checker.etsi.org/pub/index.php) I noticed that there were duplicate certificates in the [DSS and VRI dictionaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DiUI.jpg).You can see my code [here](https://github.com/adelinvoicu/PAdES-LT).I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: As I wrote in chat, the one Re: the duplicates in the /DSS/Certs dictionaries, I'll fix soon. It's because these items are added in the COSArray instead of properly using a HashSet / HashMap first. The others may be the same cause, this may take longer. (In the worst case, you can fix this yourself by fetching these, putting it into a CRT / Certificate set, and then reconstructing the COSArray from the Set)

Comment: Indeed, the code contains the comment "may lead to duplicate certificates. Important?" in a central method, so duplicate certificates should not surprise...

Comment: I've fixed the part about /DSS/Certs, can you run it again with the modified code, tell what's double and also explain what the colors mean? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5388

Comment: I run the updated code.[Here](https://imgur.com/a/HUYovaQ) you can see the DSS dictionary of the PDF document and some screenshots where you can see the minimum requirements for LT and LTA.I found this signed documents [here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-pdf-advanced-electronic-signature-pades/1103) and I introduced them in ETSI Signature Conformance Checker . I really don't know what colors mean.I noticed that our code also introduce the data for the LTA before attaching the timestamp signature,but I think this is not a problem.

Comment: First the timestamp, then the validation. But your original file already had a timestamp signature. I just ran AddValidation on that file. Nothing is duplicate. Here's the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s11C6Eb0BhgngfAia6z7R3-tMj0d9ncU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: _But your original file already had a timestamp signature_.My original file ,PAdES-LT signed,doesn't has a timestamp signature.Timetamp signature is a second signature.You can see [here](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/pdf/examples/c-sharp-vb-net-pdf-advanced-electronic-signature-pades/1103#pades-b-lta) a document with timestamp singnature.

Comment: I also created a [PAdES-LTA singed PDF](https://github.com/adelinvoicu/PAdES-LT/blob/main/Resources/sample_signed_LT_TimestampSignature.pdf) (LTA level is like the B-LT level but adds validation-related information for the signature's timestamp to the DSS and a document timestamp to the PDF document.) using `CreateSignedTimeStamp`.Validation-Related Information for the signature's timestamp was already in DSS.

Comment: ok what I meant to say is that the signature of the original file itself had an embedded timetamp token, so why an extra signature AFTER doing the LT stuff? My understanding is this: If it hadn't a timestamp, then you could run the CreateSignedTimeStamp (which adds a TimeStamp signature) or ValidationTimeStamp (which replaces the exising signature by one with a timestamp token) example, and THEN do the AddValidationInformation stuff.

Comment: You can see [here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103100_103199/103172/02.01.01_60/ts_103172v020101p.pdf) [9]Requirements for LTA-Level Conformance

Comment: OK you're right, an additional timestamp is to be done after doing the DSS stuff even if there was a timestamp before. I looked at the file `sample_signed_LT_TimestampSignature.pdf`, there is no duplicate certificate in the DSS.

Comment: I also noticed that CRLs can be double in /DSS/CRLs. However this isn't relevant in production because reputable organisations provide OCSP, so I don't think this has to be fixed.

Comment: Now, I have another question.If I have 2 signatures (my signature and timestamp signature) should I have 2 VRI dictionaries(one for my signature and one for timestamp singnature)? @mkl

Comment: One for every signature that was done before running AddValidation. This includes signatures for CRLs and for OCSP responses. But the extra signature you mentioned a few hours ago, my understanding is that this is not part of the DSS. But I'm not a signature expert (mkl is).

Comment: Well, if you try to create a LTA signature, you have the final document time stamp for which you cannot have a VRI dictionary yet. Other than that, both earlier document time stamps and document signatures (and also revocation information signatures as @Tilman mentioned) get their own VRI dictionaries. Signature time stamps are a bit weird in this context, they used to get their own in the wording of the original PAdES technical specifications, but in the wording of the current PAdES norm they don't.

Comment: All that being said, though, please remember that the VRI structure is optional. More to the point, the PAdES norm even recommends *against* using it for baseline signatures: "The VRI dictionary should not be used." (ETSI EN 319 142-1 V1.1.1 section 6.3 requirement v). Thus, as far as PAdES is concerned, you are better off _not_ using the VRI dictionaries at all and simply collecting all needed validation related information in the global *Certs*, *OCSPs*, and *CRLs* arrays. Adobe Reader _used_ to strictly require VRI dictionaries but also gave up on that some years ago.

Comment: So,I should stop using the VRI dictionary

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Could you please help me make a version of `AddValidationInformation` that uses only the DSS dictionary?I tried to do this myself, but I get some weird errors.

Comment: No, but the easiest would be to add `dss.removeItem(COSName.getPDFName("VRI"));` just before saving.